# Find common elements that are in the same order in two lists Python

Tags: python, list

Just have a quick question about python. I was wondering if there was any simple pythonic way to take two list such as:

```
a = ['t', 'o', 'a', 'c']
b = ['c', 't', 'a', 'o']
```

and then return the common elements/chars that are also in the same order relative to each other between the two lists.

```
# possible outputs for this list could be either:
output: ['t', 'a']
output: ['t', 'o']
```

I can initially start with two lists and extract the matching elements
while still keeping the order in tact by doing this:

```
c = ['z', 't', 'o', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'f']
d = ['e', 'q', 'c', 't', 'a', 'o', 'y']
a = [x for x in c if x in d]
b = [x for x in d if x in c]
```

Which will give me the original a and b lists. However, I wasn't able to find a away to reduce this further. Tried using sets but that doesn't keep the order of the elements. I know an easy way would probably just be brute for and n^2 to compare one list to another in place, but I am trying to avoid that and find a solution that would find the largest match in two lists relative to each other.

Comment: What have you tried? Also have you looked into topological sort?

Comment: 'a' is the only element in the same order, shouldn't that be the result?

Comment: @nfnneil, 'a' is in the same position/index, I think OP is asking for relative order of the elements to each other ('c' is after 'o' in `a` but before in `b`)

Comment: @nfnneil as R Nar mentioned, I am trying to find relative order which I updated the question to say. Sorry about that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the [Longest Common Subsequence Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).  **It is NP-hard**.  That's a well known problem, so you may google it for code samples.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['t', 'o', 'a', 'c']
>>> b = ['c', 't', 'a', 'o']

>>> [i for i in itertools.combinations(a, 2) if i in  itertools.combinations(b, 2)]

[('t', 'o'), ('t', 'a')]
```

Edit:

To get all

```
>>> c = ['z', 't', 'o', 'x', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'g']
>>> d = ['e', 'q', 'c', 't', 'a', 'g', 'o', 'y']

>>> def f(l):
...  r = []
...  for i in range(2, len(l)+1):
...   r += itertools.combinations(l, i)
...  return r
>>>
>>> [i for i in f(c) if i in f(d)]

[('t', 'o'), ('t', 'a'), ('t', 'g'), ('a', 'g'), ('c', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 'g')]
```

Or:

```
>>> def f(l):
...     return [j for i in range(2, len(l)+1) for j in list(itertools.combinations(l, i))]
>>>
>>> [i for i in f(c) if i in f(d)]

[('t', 'o'), ('t', 'a'), ('t', 'g'), ('a', 'g'), ('c', 'g'), ('t', 'a', 'g')]
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining the idea in words.

Comment: I like this solution alot! However, after playing with this, I see that the for range will cause lists like c = ['i', 't'] and d = ['m', 'i', 't'] to fail

Comment: @JackLiaiea sorry, try now